# WP functions.php url with variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this:

```
printf( '<cite class="fn"><a href="http://www.xxx.it/dialogueroom/?page_id=64&username=">%s</a></cite>', get_comment_author_link() );
```

and i want to build my url wit %s variable

something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.xxx.it/dialogueroom/?page_id=64&username=%s">%s</a>
```

but it doesn't work.

can you help me?

thanks!

S

Comment: `print_f`/`sprint_f` would not replace two occurrences unless you've provided two arguments. Perhaps you're looking for `str_replace`?

Comment: i'm not php user, i'm looking for a rapid solution :P

Answer (score 1):

To have more than one placeholder in a string cf. [argument swapping](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php#example-4273):

```
printf( 
    '<cite class="fn"><a href="http://www.xxx.it/dialogueroom/?page_id=64&username=%1$s">%2$s</a></cite>',
    $username,
    get_comment_author_link()
);
```

Comment: in the builded link misses the variable

Comment: The above assumes the username is in a variable `$username`; you should probably also urlencode it: `urlencode($username)`

Comment: but i think it is the right way.. i have to work on this solution. thanks a lot

Comment: btw: maybe easier to use the user ID instead of the user name?

Answer (score 0):

```
printf( '<cite class="fn"><a href="http://www.break-out.it/dialogueroom/?page_id=64&username=%1$s">%2$s</a></cite>', get_comment_author(), get_comment_author_link() );
```

this works :) thanks Diggy. the solution came from you